# ADO - How to get float field type precision an 'required' info?

Tags: database, delphi, ado, c++builder, vcl

I have MS Access database (mdb) and inside it a table with float/double fields. Inside my app I'm trying to get the precision of the field (column) and if it is set as required or no:

```
if(ADOTable1->Fields->FieldByNumber(1)->DataType == ftFloat)
ShowMessage(TFloatField(ADOTable1->Fields->FieldByName(ADOTable1->Fields->FieldByNumber(1)->FieldName)).Precision);
```

to check 'required':

```
if(ADOTable1->Fields->FieldByNumber(1)->Required == true)
    ShowMessage("Yes");
else
    ShowMessage("No"); // It's always "No" for every field
```

Both fail to give me the correct result. What am I doing wrong?

I use C++ Builder XE2, ADO components.